# Math script/writing for a "count of something"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

I was wondering if there was a formal way to write a "count of something".
For instance in my problem, I have a population of discrete entities (people) **U**, I use **u** with a subscript if I need to refer to a specific entity.
My question is: is there a convenient way to write "the count of discrete **u**" ? Possibly without using a sum (Sigma), it's a bit "bulky".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your population of discrete entities is $U$, and the individual entities are denoted $u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n$, then we can just write that as a **set**:
$$U = \{u_1,u_2, \ldots, u_n\}$$
And we usually denote cardinality of a set (the number of elements in the set) with bars, like this: $|U|$. So $|U|$ is the number of 'people' in your 'population', in other words, it is the count!